# How can I add a segue identifier to a programmatically modal transition?

Tags: swift, swift3, modalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have a controller which is in the Main storyboard. When I click on a button, I call the `displayBorneDetailsAction()` action, it presents a modal view from another storyboard.

I would add a Segue identifier when I present my modal to pass data from my main view controller to my modal view controller (with `prepareForSegue`), but I don't know how to do it.

**I tried to use `performSegue(withIdentifier:)`, but it doesn't present the modal in the same way.**

```
@IBAction func displayBorneDetailsAction(_ sender: Any) {
    // open the modal of a borne
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Borne", bundle: nil)
    let vc: BorneVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BorneVC") as! BorneVC

    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overFullScreen
    navigationController.edgesForExtendedLayout = []

    self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You cannot add an identifier to a programmatical segue**, since you are able to access the instance of the controller that is being presented. Simply do anything you want with the controller in the function where you present it.